# Android sound loop

Tags: android, audio, time, camera-flash

I am developing an Android application that converts morse code to sounds and flashes. The flashes part works well, but I'm having troubles with sound part.

here is the code I have so far:

```
SoundPool sp =new SoundPool.Builder().setMaxStreams(1).build(); // declare before onCreate()
int soundId = sp.load(this,R.raw.beep,1); // declared inside onCreate()

public void flashCode(View view){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {

        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA},0);
        }
    }

    int dotTime=150;  // in milliseconds
    long ms=System.currentTimeMillis();
    long ms2=System.currentTimeMillis();

    //
    //int streamID=mSoundPool.load(this,R.raw.beep,1);
    for (int i=0;i<code.length();i++)
    {
        streamID=sp.play(soundId,1,1,1,1,1.0f);
        sp.pause(streamID);
        if (String.valueOf(code.charAt(i)).contentEquals("."))
        {
            String cameraId = null; // Usually front camera is at 0 position.
            try {
                cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];

                ms=System.currentTimeMillis();
                ms2=System.currentTimeMillis()+dotTime;

                camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
                //mSoundPool.resume(streamID);

                while (ms<ms2){
                    ms=System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
                //mSoundPool.stop(streamID);

            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (String.valueOf(code.charAt(i)).contentEquals("-"))
        {
            String cameraId = null; // Usually front camera is at 0 position.
            try {
                cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];

                ms=System.currentTimeMillis();
                ms2=System.currentTimeMillis()+dotTime*3;

                camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, true);
                //mSoundPool.resume(streamID);

                while (ms<ms2){
                    ms=System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
                camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);
                //mSoundPool.stop(streamID);

            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        if (String.valueOf(code.charAt(i)).contentEquals(" "))
        {
            String cameraId = null; // Usually front camera is at 0 position.
            try {
                cameraId = camManager.getCameraIdList()[0];

                ms=System.currentTimeMillis();
                ms2=System.currentTimeMillis()+dotTime;

                camManager.setTorchMode(cameraId, false);

                while (ms<ms2){
                    ms=System.currentTimeMillis();
                }


            } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want is the play a sound when I turn flash on and off, but only during that time. I tried with `SoundPool` but when I tested it out, the flash and sounds weren't synced and `MediaPlayer` it even skipped some sounds.

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong or tell me how would you do it.

Comment: why are you pausing soundpool immeadiately after play? and you should not play it inside for loop.

Comment: well i did it this way because i already had the same code for flash. I thought i will be able to do in the same manner with sounnds

Comment: i moved `sp.play` out of for and added added -1 to loop and it works perfectly thank you